Change Color of Dynamically created elements in React + React Hook Form
I'm using React Hook forms to create some dynamic forms.
React Hook Forms has a function for creating repeatable elements called useFieldArray.
In some of these repeatable, dynamic elements I need to be able to change style attributes based on user selection.
I'm not sure how to target the styling of an element that is created dynamically. Anyone come across this problem and figure it out?

Is this based on a user selection in the form, or a selection somewhere else in the app?  If based on a user selection in the form, react-hook-form has the useWatch hook which will allow a component to watch form values and react accordingly.

No code, probably no help...
